# Image Height Appear Different on different density

Tags: android

I'm new in designing the layouts. I am getting the bitmap from the server and I'm setting the imageview height such that it look good on every density either ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi.

```
stripImageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) ((Util.screenWidth(this) * strip.getHeight() / strip.getWidth()) * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

But This code not working for me. Some device images looking very small and Some device it look fine

Answer (score 0):

Try just setting the dimensions in your layout using dp instead of px. Dp (or dip) stands for density independent pixels and will automatically scale based on density.

EDIT: another issue I see is that you're referencing both the screen width and height so your screen aspect ratio would also affect that calculation.

Comment: `stripImageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) ((Util.screenWidth(this) * strip.getHeight() / strip.getWidth()) * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);` How to do that. It would be good if you update my code

Comment: I can't set the imageview height fix in dp in the layout. So I set this at runtime according to the strip height and width. If Any wrong let me know

Comment: So What is the solution of this

Answer (score 0):

convert them to DIP:

```
stripImageView.getLayoutParams(). height = 
     (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, <HEIGHT>, 
          getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

where HEIGHT is the height in px you want.  You could base it off the strip height or something.

Comment: Is this return in px `(Util.screenWidth(this) * strip.getHeight() / strip.getWidth()` `public static int screenWidth(Context ctx) {
  WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx
    .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
  Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
  return display.getWidth();
 }`

Comment: getHeight, getwidth, and screenWidth retrun values in px